# [Android11+]why SurfaceComposerClient.h render in native process,the layer is always higher than the windowManager.addView in the application window?

Tags: android, surfaceview, surface, android-11

The surafce level setting of the native process is 0+, the application app window type is WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY. How can I make the app window level higher than the screen rendered by the native process(app window is displayed on top)

[dumpsys SurfaceFlinger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g1Vo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTrot.png)

```
    SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction{}
        .setLayer(control, 0)
        .setPosition(control, area.startX/10, area.startY/10)
        .setSize(control, area.endX/10 - area.startX/10, area.endY/10 - area.startY/10)
        .apply();
```

app window is displayed on top of native surface

```
dumpsys SurfaceFlinger
Display 0 HWC layers:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Layer name
           Z |  Window Type |  Comp Type |  Transform |   Disp Frame (LTRB) |          Source Crop (LTRB) |     Frame Rate (Explicit) [Focused]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 com.streamax.nxm.app/com.streamax.nxm.standard.preview.PreviewActivity#0
  rel      0 |            1 |     CLIENT |          0 |    0    0 1920 1080 |    0.0    0.0 1920.0 1080.0 |                              [*]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 Sys2038:com.streamax.nxm.app/com.str[...]m.standard.preview.PreviewActivity#0
  rel      0 |         2038 |     CLIENT |          0 |    0    0 1920 1080 |    0.0    0.0 1920.0 1080.0 |                              [ ]            I want to other window on the top
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
 surface#0
           0 |            0 |     CLIENT |          0 |    0    0  960  540 |    0.0    0.0  960.0  540.0 |                              [ ]            surface#0~2 always on the top is wrong in my scence
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -                
 surface#1
           0 |            0 |     CLIENT |          0 |  960    0 1920  540 |    0.0    0.0  960.0  540.0 |                              [ ]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 surface#2
           0 |            0 |     CLIENT |          0 |    0  540  960 1080 |    0.0    0.0  960.0  540.0 |                              [ ]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: two process: app process(use windowmanager.addView), native c++ process(use SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction setLayer)